# how to display the date between the from and to range of date in php

Tags: php, arrays, date, echo

How do I display a range of dates from `28-10-2014` to `01-11-2014`?

```
28-10-2014
29-10-2014
30-10-2014
31-10-2014
01-11-2014
```

Comment: So you want to be able to print a series of dates given a range, right?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ya i tried to convert the from and to date in the strtotime and tried to increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$begin = new DateTime('28-10-2014');
$end = new DateTime('01-11-2014');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("m-d-Y");
}

?>
```

Comment: end date is not printing in this

Comment: 10-28-2014
10-29-2014
10-30-2014
10-31-2014
only printing

Comment: @RajaManickam Replace `$datarange` with this `$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end->modify( '+1 day' ));`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = "10-28-2014";
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$iterations = 4;
for ($i=0 ; $i<=  $iterations ; $i++) {
  $tomorrow = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date1 . "+$i days"));
  echo '<br/>'.$tomorrow;
}
?>
```

Hope this works.